# How to import bson into neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, bson

Looking for some starting point to import bson to neo4j. I code in Java but any other language or Unix script would do. I could not find tutorials or any google result (that is why there is no coding draft here).

Answer (score 0):

There is NO way to import data into neo4j without coding a bit (except load csv and neo4j-import)

I don't see what is the problem with json, bson, xml, or whatever format exist in the world, the steps are simple

1. You read the file with the appropriate file reader for the format
2. You convert to objects/maps/arrays
3. You create Cypher queries
4. You send them to neo4j with the neo4j-driver

This is completely independent of any language or any source format.